# Website debugging fails because of port mismatch

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am debugging a MVC4 application using VS2012. I press F5 in VS IDE. Then 'ASP.net development Server' gets launched and the tool-tip(shown in the bottom-right corner)

```
says http://localhost:9553
```

Then FireFox gets launched with URL

```
http://localhost:43297/default.aspx
```

Browser fails to connect to web-server. This is obvious because 'ASP.net development Server' is listening on 9553 but the browser is connecting to 43297.

If any one knows reason for this port mismatch, please let me know.

(There is an another way to know the port being used by 'ASP.net development Server'. First, keep  'ASP.net development Server' running. Then use ProcExp.exe to look at the command-line parameters used for launching WebDev.WebServer40.exe. That cmd-line parameter will have port number. In this case port is 9553)

Comment: can you tell us what is under the `Web` tab in the Project Properties? (right click your project in solution explorer and select `Properties`) - am interested in whether either or both of those URLs are mentioned anywhere in those settings

Comment: You can assign a static port from your project properties and then Web tab

Comment: Thanks for your response. Under 'Properties-->Web', 'Start Url' = http://localhost:43297/default.aspx so this solves the problem. Auto-Assign-port has been checked. Auto-Assign-port is used by 'ASP.net development Server' and 'Start Url' applies to Browser.

Comment: @wal has answered my question. Thanks

Comment: @wal I do not see 'answered' option. I think that is supposed to be  right mark in green color.

Comment: @user1174790 I have added my answer below. you can now mark as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what is under the Web tab in the Project Properties? (right click your project in solution explorer and select Properties) - am interested in whether either or both of those URLs are mentioned anywhere in those settings. Specifically what is in `Start URL` and `Project URL` fields.

You should clear out any setting in `Start URL` and leave anything in `Project URL`